# registry key error

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, boot, windows-registry

When I start my computer I get a pop up – registry 2. Key_error [RegOpenKeyEx() failed: key “community” (2)]   I also get the same pop up when I open Outlook. I am running Windows 7 - 64 bit. I installed the Outlook from an older version of Microsoft Office 2003. And I run Microsoft Office 2007 for everything else. I don’t get the pop up when I open office 2007 but it doesn’t have the Outlook in it. I uninstalled Office 2003 and reinstalled only the Outlook but no change, and I’m not even sure that is the problem. I went in to the registry to try and find the string but I can’t seem to locate it. Any ideas that would be helpful would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) can be very helpful here – just tell it to show registry accesses, include "outlook.exe", exclude "SUCCESS", and look for anything unusual.